# Showing a custom field in reviews on the front end Magento 2

Tags: magento2, review, addfield

I have created various new fields in Magento 2.3.1 in the review_details table

They are created and in my UpdateSchema and added to the table,

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('review_detail'),
        'reviewee_location', /* Reviewee location summary i.e. 'Wigan, Lancashire' */
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            'length' => 100,
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 'Reviewee Location'
        ]
    );
```

I have managed to add them to the backend to the admin and can enter data and save it without a problem.

My ReviewSave.php

```
<?php

namespace bub\bubreviews\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ReviewSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }

    public function convertDate($date){
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);
        return date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $review = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
        $connection = $this->_resource;
        $tableName = $connection->getTableName('review_detail');
        $detail = [
            'email' => $review->getEmail(),
            'review_date' => $review->getReviewDate(),
            'purchase_date' => $review->getPurchaseDate(),
            'confirmed_purchase' => $review->getConfirmedPurchase(),
            'reviewee_location' => $review->getRevieweeLocation(),          
        ];

        $detail['review_date'] = $this->convertDate($review->getReviewDate()); 
        $detail['purchase_date'] = $this->convertDate($review->getPurchaseDate());


        $select = $connection->getConnection()->select()->from($tableName)->where('review_id = :review_id');
        $detailId = $connection->getConnection()->fetchOne($select, [':review_id' => $review->getId()]);

        if ($detailId) {
            $condition = ["detail_id = ?" => $detailId];
            $connection->getConnection()->update($tableName, $detail, $condition);
        } else {
            $detail['store_id'] = $review->getStoreId();
            $detail['customer_id'] = $review->getCustomerId();
            $detail['review_id'] = $review->getId();
            $connection->getConnection()->insert($tableName, $detail);
        }   

    }

}
```

I've now come to add the data to the front end and I can't understand why I can't get the field to display, I must be missing something really simple

My code to add it to the frontend in magento/app/design/frontend/bub/mytheme/Magento_Review/templates/product/viewlist.phtml

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView $block */

$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();
$format = $block->getDateFormat() ?: \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT;
?>
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
<div class="block review-list" id="customer-reviews">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Customer Reviews')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
        <ol class="items review-items">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
            <li class="item review-item" itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
                <div class="review-title" itemprop="name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?></div>
                <?php if (count($_review->getRatingVotes())): ?>
                    <div class="review-ratings">
                    <?php foreach ($_review->getRatingVotes() as $_vote): ?>
                    <div class="rating-summary item" itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
                        <span class="label rating-label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></span></span>
                        <div class="rating-result" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%">
                            <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
                            <meta itemprop="bestRating" content = "100"/>
                            <span style="width:<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%">
                                <span itemprop="ratingValue"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_vote->getPercent()) ?>%</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="review-content" itemprop="description">
                    <?= nl2br($block->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="review-details">
                    <p class="review-author">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Review by')) ?></span>
                        <strong class="review-details-value" itemprop="author"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname()) ?></strong>
                    </p>
                    <p class="review-date">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Posted on')) ?></span>
                        <time class="review-details-value" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt(), $format)) ?></time>
                    </p>
                    <p class="reviewee-location">
                        <span class="review-details-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Reviewee Location')) ?></span>
                        <strong class="review-details-value" itemprop="location"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_review->getRevieweeLocation()) ?></strong>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
        <div class="toolbar review-toolbar">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

**Collection.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review;

/**
 * Review collection resource model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * Review table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reviewTable = null;

    /**
     * Review detail table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reviewDetailTable = null;

    /**
     * Review status table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reviewStatusTable = null;

    /**
     * Review entity table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reviewEntityTable = null;

    /**
     * Review store table
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_reviewStoreTable = null;

    /**
     * Add store data flag
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_addStoreDataFlag = false;

    /**
     * Review data
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_reviewData = null;

    /**
     * Rating option model
     *
     * @var \Magento\Review\Model\Rating\Option\VoteFactory
     */
    protected $_voteFactory;

    /**
     * Core model store manager interface
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\Review\Helper\Data $reviewData
     * @param \Magento\Review\Model\Rating\Option\VoteFactory $voteFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param mixed $connection
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Review\Helper\Data $reviewData,
        \Magento\Review\Model\Rating\Option\VoteFactory $voteFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_reviewData = $reviewData;
        $this->_voteFactory = $voteFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;

        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $connection, $resource);
    }

    /**
     * Define module
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::class, \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review::class);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize select
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['detail' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()],
            'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id',
            ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id', 'review_source' , 'reviewee_location']
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add customer filter
     *
     * @param int|string $customerId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addCustomerFilter($customerId)
    {
        $this->addFilter('customer', $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('detail.customer_id=?', $customerId), 'string');
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add store filter
     *
     * @param int|int[] $storeId
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addStoreFilter($storeId)
    {
        $inCond = $this->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition('store.store_id', ['in' => $storeId]);
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['store' => $this->getReviewStoreTable()],
            'main_table.review_id=store.review_id',
            []
        );
        $this->getSelect()->where($inCond);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add stores data
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addStoreData()
    {
        $this->_addStoreDataFlag = true;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add entity filter
     *
     * @param int|string $entity
     * @param int $pkValue
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addEntityFilter($entity, $pkValue)
    {
        $reviewEntityTable = $this->getReviewEntityTable();
        if (is_numeric($entity)) {
            $this->addFilter('entity', $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('main_table.entity_id=?', $entity), 'string');
        } elseif (is_string($entity)) {
            $this->_select->join(
                $reviewEntityTable,
                'main_table.entity_id=' . $reviewEntityTable . '.entity_id',
                ['entity_code']
            );

            $this->addFilter(
                'entity',
                $this->getConnection()->quoteInto($reviewEntityTable . '.entity_code=?', $entity),
                'string'
            );
        }

        $this->addFilter(
            'entity_pk_value',
            $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('main_table.entity_pk_value=?', $pkValue),
            'string'
        );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add status filter
     *
     * @param int|string $status
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addStatusFilter($status)
    {
        if (is_string($status)) {
            $statuses = array_flip($this->_reviewData->getReviewStatuses());
            $status = isset($statuses[$status]) ? $statuses[$status] : 0;
        }
        if (is_numeric($status)) {
            $this->addFilter('status', $this->getConnection()->quoteInto('main_table.status_id=?', $status), 'string');
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set date order
     *
     * @param string $dir
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDateOrder($dir = 'DESC')
    {
        $this->setOrder('main_table.created_at', $dir);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add rate votes
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addRateVotes()
    {
        foreach ($this->getItems() as $item) {
            $votesCollection = $this->_voteFactory->create()->getResourceCollection()->setReviewFilter(
                $item->getId()
            )->setStoreFilter(
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->addRatingInfo(
                $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
            )->load();
            $item->setRatingVotes($votesCollection);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add reviews total count
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addReviewsTotalCount()
    {
        $this->_select->joinLeft(
            ['r' => $this->getReviewTable()],
            'main_table.entity_pk_value = r.entity_pk_value',
            ['total_reviews' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(r.review_id)')]
        )->group(
            'main_table.review_id'
        );

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Load data
     *
     * @param boolean $printQuery
     * @param boolean $logQuery
     * @return $this
     */
    public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
    {
        if ($this->isLoaded()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('review_review_collection_load_before', ['collection' => $this]);
        parent::load($printQuery, $logQuery);
        if ($this->_addStoreDataFlag) {
            $this->_addStoreData();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add store data
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _addStoreData()
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();

        $reviewsIds = $this->getColumnValues('review_id');
        $storesToReviews = [];
        if (count($reviewsIds) > 0) {
            $inCond = $connection->prepareSqlCondition('review_id', ['in' => $reviewsIds]);
            $select = $connection->select()->from($this->getReviewStoreTable())->where($inCond);
            $result = $connection->fetchAll($select);
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if (!isset($storesToReviews[$row['review_id']])) {
                    $storesToReviews[$row['review_id']] = [];
                }
                $storesToReviews[$row['review_id']][] = $row['store_id'];
            }
        }

        foreach ($this as $item) {
            if (isset($storesToReviews[$item->getId()])) {
                $item->setStores($storesToReviews[$item->getId()]);
            } else {
                $item->setStores([]);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get review table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getReviewTable()
    {
        if ($this->_reviewTable === null) {
            $this->_reviewTable = $this->getTable('review');
        }
        return $this->_reviewTable;
    }

    /**
     * Get review detail table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getReviewDetailTable()
    {
        if ($this->_reviewDetailTable === null) {
            $this->_reviewDetailTable = $this->getTable('review_detail');
        }
        return $this->_reviewDetailTable;
    }

    /**
     * Get review status table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getReviewStatusTable()
    {
        if ($this->_reviewStatusTable === null) {
            $this->_reviewStatusTable = $this->getTable('review_status');
        }
        return $this->_reviewStatusTable;
    }

    /**
     * Get review entity table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getReviewEntityTable()
    {
        if ($this->_reviewEntityTable === null) {
            $this->_reviewEntityTable = $this->getTable('review_entity');
        }
        return $this->_reviewEntityTable;
    }

    /**
     * Get review store table
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getReviewStoreTable()
    {
        if ($this->_reviewStoreTable === null) {
            $this->_reviewStoreTable = $this->getTable('review_store');
        }
        return $this->_reviewStoreTable;
    }
}
```

This is what works but if I just paste the code in your Collection.php it fails

Also how do I order the collection

```
$_items = $block->getReviewsCollection()->setOrder('review_source', 'ASC');
```

doesn't work and I've established that it's because setOrder isn't a method of $block but how do I acheive this?

New error:-

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Select_Exception): You cannot define a correlation name 'detail' more than once

Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Select_Exception): You cannot define a correlation name 'detail' more than once
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\DB\Select->_join('inner join', array('detail' => 'review_detail'), 'main_table.revie...', array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id', 'review_source', 'reviewee_locatio...'), NULL) called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php:357]
#2 Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(array('detail' => 'review_detail'), 'main_table.revie...', array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id', 'review_source', 'reviewee_locatio...'), NULL) called at [vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Select.php:336]
#3 Zend_Db_Select->join(array('detail' => 'review_detail'), 'main_table.revie...', array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id', 'review_source', 'reviewee_locatio...')) called at [app/code/bub/bubreviews/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Collection.php:27]
#4 bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection->_initSelect() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/Collection/AbstractCollection.php:133]
```

With Collection.php like below I get the above error

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Ãƒâ€šÃ‚Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review;

/**
 * Review collection resource model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */ 
class Collection extends \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection
{    
    /**
     * Initialize select
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['detail' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()],
            'main_table.review_id = detail.review_id',
            ['detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id', 'review_source' , 'reviewee_location']
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked your code and everything is fine with your module files and the template file for the review listing.

For displaying it on the frontend, you need to override the `_initSelect()` function in `Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection` Magento class in your module and add your custom parameter `reviewee_location` to add it in the collection to get it in your phtml file on review collection load.

Add below code in your `bub\bubreviews\etc\di.xml` to add a preference for this class.

```
<preference for="Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection" type="bub\bubreviews\Model\Rewrite\Review\Collection" />
```

Create `Collection.php` file on the below path.

`bub\bubreviews\Model\Rewrite\Review`

Below is the code you need to add after creating a preference for the Magento class `Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection` in your module.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace bub\bubreviews\Model\Rewrite\Review;

/**
 * Review collection resource model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection
{
    /**
     * Initialize select
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['review_detail' => $this->getReviewDetailTable()],
            'main_table.review_id = review_detail.review_id',
            ['reviewee_location']
        );
        return parent::_initSelect();
    }
}
```

After doing this, please run below commands to reflect the changes on the frontend.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Hope this will helpful for you!!!**

Comment: Thanks Sumit I also had to obviously copy the original collection.php and then change the namespace bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review;
but it then worked thanks for your help

Comment: You can, but it's not necessary. You can just copy the function you want to override.

Comment: tried that but then got page error 500 on another point how can I change the order of a collection specifically getReviewsCollection()->getItems() i've tried SetOrder('review_source', 'ASC') but it just ignores it

Comment: Can you please enable the error from bootstrap.php and share it with me?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED), expecting end of file in /var/www/vhosts/bubit.co.uk/httpdocs/magento/app/code/bub/bubreviews/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Collection.php on line 13

Comment: Please update your question with this file app/code/bub/bubreviews/Model/ResourceModel/Review/Collection.php so I can check it.

Comment: Added Also with another question thanks for all your help Sumit, I used to develop in magento ver 1.5 years ago

Comment: You need to extend your Collection class with \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection instead of using   \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection

Comment: Do you mean just change the line in Collection.php, or am I using the wrong collection in the first place sorry i'm confused

Comment: You need to extend with the class you are using in the preference in di.xml

Comment: if I change the the extend class to \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection it throws an error`code`<?php
/**
 * Copyright Ã‚Â© Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review;

/**
 * Review collection resource model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Collection extends \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection
{`code`

Comment: ** error is :-** Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: bub\bubreviews\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('bub\bubr

Comment: The interceptor file needs to be re-created. Kindly run php bin/magento setup:di:compile and
php  bin/magento  cache:clean

Comment: Now getting a new error posted in original Question, I take it that this is because it's not over-writing the original Collection.php function?

Comment: I've updated your Collection.php, please check and try. Kindly run php bin/magento s:up, php bin/magento setup:di:compile and php bin/magento cache:clean after the changes.

Comment: Hi, Sumit sorry that's exactly what i'm using as Collection.php now, could it be that the original \Magento\Review\Model\ResourceModel\Review\Collection which I'm extending in turn extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection?

Comment: hence it works if I copy the whole Collection.php and extend \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection but doesn't when I just try and extend the Extension of the extension

Comment: OK, let me check it once.

Comment: I've updated my Collection.php as per your need. This is code tested and it is working fine. Hope it'll help you to fix the issue.
Please accept the answer if it is useful for you. :)

Comment: Cant see a new version of Collection.php

Comment: I've updated my code. Please check my comment for Collection.php

Comment: Thanks for your help Sumit that's solved it,

Comment: Finally :D, Good to hear.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98331/discussion-on-answer-by-sumit-showing-a-custom-field-in-reviews-on-the-front-end).